# VoIP equivalent of Coretelephony

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, voip, objective-c-2.0, core-telephony

I have Coretelephony working for monitoring incoming and outgoing calls, however, I also needs this functionality for VoIP calls. Is there are framework with similar features as coretelephony but for VoIP calls?

Comment: sigh, guess there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent at all, and in fact it is not possible to do anything like this at all with out jailbreak.

I ended scouring the iOS docs, nothing nada ziltch. Nothing for iOS7 it looks like either.